# Accessing a class field using a string

Tags: c#, class, reflection, field

I have a class name DB.IFCArray which have plenty of fields in it (name, description etc), I want to implement a function
that goes to the DB.IFCArray.field and do stuff..

```
public static bool if_is_a(DB.IFCArray object1, string field, string value)
        {            
            if (object1.field == value) // this ofc not working, but hope you get the idea
            return true;

            return false;
         }
```

Comment: Search the web for "reflection". Also please note you _almost never_ require reflection, as most problems can be solved more elegantly using the appropriate object-oriented constructs as interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
//get the property indicated by parameter 'field'
//Use 'GetField' here if they are actually fields as opposed to Properties
//although the merits of a public field are dubious...
       var prop = object1.GetType().GetProperty(field);
//if it exists
        if (prop!=null)
        {
          //get its value from the object1 instance, and compare
          //if using Fields, leave out the 'null' in this next line:
          var propValue = prop.GetValue(object1,null);

          if (propValue==null) return false;
          return propValue;
        }
        else
        {
          //throw an exception for property not found
        }
```

But as CodeCaster mentioned above, I'd recommend you take a look at your design and see if this is really necessary. What is the bigger picture here? Unless you absolutely 100% will not know the property names until runtime, there's almost always a better way...

Comment: Ty. I have to use Reflection for this, but just one issue with the code you suggested, it seems prop is null even when 'field' contain exactly the name of one of the properties in object1. Could there be any slight mistake in the code?

Comment: @user2915058 - you are absolutely right, my apologies. Code is updated above (the line `return propValue==value` is changed to `return propValue`). Looks like a copy-paste accident on my part :)

Comment: Still not what I meant, maybe its bad from my part, let me explain:
prop, in the line (var prop = object1.GetType().GetProperty(field);) is null, even if i put the correct field name. 

object1 definition is:
 public static class DB
    {
        public class IFCArray
        {
            public string globalID;
            public string Element_Type;
            public string name;
            etc...

so even if I put 
prop = object1.GetType().GetProperty("name");
it returns prop as null, 
Whats the issue here?

Comment: @user2915058 - `GetProperty` will of course only work on Properties, not Fields - you should use `GetField` instead. See update.

Comment: Super, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think error is showing due to type error in the  `if (object1.field == value)` statement.
use reflection to get type of the field and compare the value according to the type.

Hope this helps,
Thanks.